# I tried to stop the user registering with already registered data and i tried with UNIQUE key also but not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I tried to stop the user registering with duplicate data and I used UNIQUE Key,Primary Key like that, and also so many ways searched in StackOverflow but still not worked..can any body please help me to solve this

```
    package com.example.dell.foodcourt;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.sax.StartElementListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase{
        Context context;
        FoodCourt_LoginData foodCourt_loginData;
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        public FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase(Context context){
            foodCourt_loginData=new FoodCourt_LoginData(context);
        }
```

This is the method **insertData** to insert the data in registered data. In this method I want to stop the entering of duplicate data.

As per some suggestions I used `Conflict_Replace` but it is replacing entered data with existing data instead of blocking.

```
        public void insertData(String username,String userpwd,String usermble){

                    SQLiteDatabase db = foodCourt_loginData.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME, username);
                    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERPWD, userpwd);
                    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERMOBILE, usermble);
                    db.insertWithOnConflict(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        }

        public String viewData(){

            SQLiteDatabase db=foodCourt_loginData.getWritableDatabase(); //calling database to get writable data
            String[] cloumn={FoodCourt_LoginData.ID,FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME,FoodCourt_LoginData.USERPWD};  //stroing all the values in String array
            //Cursor is used to call the Stored data in Database and it starts data reading from row1 and moveToNext will call from upto end of data
            Cursor cursor=db.query(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME,cloumn,null,null,null,null,null);
            StringBuffer Buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                int cid=cursor.getInt(0);
                String Name=cursor.getString(1);
                String Password=cursor.getString(2);
                Buffer.append(cid+" "+Name+" "+Password+" "+"\n");
            }
            return Buffer.toString();
        }

        public String Login(String Uname){
            SQLiteDatabase db=foodCourt_loginData.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] column={FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME,FoodCourt_LoginData.USERPWD};
            Cursor cursor=db.query(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME,column,null,null,null,null,null);
            String a,b;
            b="not found";
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    a=cursor.getString(0);
                    b=cursor.getString(1);
                    if(a.equals(Uname)){
                        b=cursor.getString(1);
                        break;
                    }
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
            return b;
        }

        static class FoodCourt_LoginData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FOODCOURT_LOGINDATABASE.sqlite";
            private static final String TABLENAME = "FOODCOURT_LOGIN";
            private static final String ID = "id";
            private static final String USERNAME = "UserNAME";
            private static final String USERPWD = "UserPwd";
            private static final String USERADDRESS = "Address";
            private static final String USERMOBILE = "Mobile";
            private static final String USEREMAIL = "Email";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=4;
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            private Context context;
            private static final String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLENAME+" ("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ USERNAME + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE," + USERPWD + " VARCHAR(255)," + USERADDRESS + " VARCHAR(300)," + USERMOBILE + " INTEGER(10)," + USEREMAIL + " VARCHAR(30))";
            private static final String DropTable="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '"+TABLENAME+"'";
            public FoodCourt_LoginData(Context context){
                super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
                this.context=context;
            }
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                try{
                    db.execSQL(CreateTable);
                    this.db=db;
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    Message.message(context," "+e);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DropTable);
                    onCreate(db);
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    Message.message(context," "+e);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I rely on checking for the uniqueness, amongst other things, directly, rather than relying upon constraints, key unqiness e.g :-

I get a cursor using the username as the whereclause/whereargs (`WHERE USERNAME="username"`), if the cursor count isn't 0 then it's not a unique id.

```
boolean addUser(String UserName, String Password, int UserType) {
    last_error_code = ERRCODE_NOERROR;
    last_error_message = "";
    boolean rv = true;
    long inserted;

    String whereclause =
                    DBUsertableConstants.USERNAME.getDBColumnName() +
                    "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{
            UserName
    };
    Cursor csr = db.query(
            DBUsertableConstants.USERS.getDBTableName(),
            null,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,null,null
    );
    if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
        last_error_code = ERRCODE_USEREXISTS;
        last_error_message = ERRMSG_USEREXISTS;
    }
    if (Password.length() < LoginActivity.MINPASSWORDLENGTH) {
        last_error_code = ERRCODE_PASSWORDSHORT;
        last_error_message = ERRMSG_PASSWORDSHORT;
    }
    csr.close();
    if (last_error_code > ERRCODE_NOERROR) {
        return false;
    }
    if (
            (UserName.length() > 0 && !mAllowBlankUser) ||
                    (UserName.length() >= 0 && mAllowBlankUser)
            ) {
        sah = new SaltandHash(Password);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (sah.ifSaltandHashOK()) {
            cv.put(DBUsertableConstants.USERNAME.getDBColumnName(),UserName);
            cv.put(DBUsertableConstants.USERHASH.getDBColumnName(),sah.getHash());
            cv.put(DBUsertableConstants.USERSALT.getDBColumnName(),sah.getSalt());
            cv.put(DBUsertableConstants.USERFLAG.getDBColumnName(),
                    UserType);
        } else {
            last_error_code = ERRCODE_PASSWORDNOTHASHED;
            last_error_message = ERRMSG_PASSWORDNOTHASHED;
            return false;
        }
        inserted = db.insert(
                DBUsertableConstants.USERS.getDBTableName(),
                null,
                cv
        );
        if (inserted < 1) {
            last_error_code = ERRCODE_INSERTERR;
            last_error_message = ERRMSG_INSERTERR;
            return false;
        } else {
            mLastUseridAdded = inserted;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To apply this to your code then you could use :-

```
public int insertData(String username,String userpwd,String usermble){

    String whereclause = FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{username};

    Cursor csr = db.query(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
        csr.close();
        return -1;
    }
    csr.close();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME, username);
    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERPWD, userpwd);
    contentValues.put(FoodCourt_LoginData.USERMOBILE, usermble);
    return db.insert(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME, null, contentValues);
    //db.insertWithOnConflict(FoodCourt_LoginData.TABLENAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
}
```

Noting that `inserData` would return a positive integer (1) for a successful insert or -1 if the insert would fail due to a duplicate USERNAME.

You would then handle the returned code in the invoking method, perhaps clearing the username input, requesting focus to the input and notifying the user of the issue..

If you wanted to protect further against duplication you could easily amend the query e.g. if you wanted to consider **mobile** as being required to be unique, then changing:-

```
    String whereclause = FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{username};
```

to

```
    String whereclause = FoodCourt_LoginData.USERNAME + 
        "=? OR " +
        FoodCourt_LoginData.USERMOBILE +
        "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{username, usermble};
```

would be all that was needed.

Comment: Hi Mike, you asked me to instead of using insertData method I have to use the above addUser() method? ??

Comment: No, the code is an example of checking for uniqueness by querying the existing data before inserting the data and not even trying to insert data if it shouldn't be inserted (e.g. if the username already exists). The example could very easily be adapted. You would probably be most interested in the first half of the code i.e. up till `if (Password.length() < LoginActivity.MINPASSWORDLENGTH) {`

Comment: Is any other suggestions or any other way to use this